# If I run program with su, will not-exported variables be available for callee?

Tags: variables, scope, sh

If I run program with following script

```
    MYVARIABLE=abc
    echo -n "Starting Callee"
    echo -n " "
    cd $CALEE_HOME
    su -s /bin/bash -c "$CALLEE_HOME/program.sh &" $CALLEE_USER
```

will program.sh know the value of `MYVARIABLE` or I should `export` it?

Answer (score 1):

No, only exported variables are visible to *any* child process.

Export converts a local *shell* variable into an inherited *environment* variable.

However, in the example you give, the variable will be expanded by your current shell *before* calling `su`, so you should have no problems (unless `CALLEE_USER` or `CALLEE_HOME` has spaces in it, but that's a separate issue related to the quoting).